# Парсинг MathJax

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4, mathjax

Подскажите пожалуйста как спарсить страницу на которой есть Mathjax.
Используя код:

```
 response = requests.post(url_ur, cookies={'PHPSESSID': cook})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('form')
for i in range(len(items)):
    ar_p.append(items[i].text)
    print(ar_p[i])
```

теряются знаки дроби, корни, степени и тд.
Пытаюсь получить формулы и выражения в том виде в котором они должны быть на сайте фипи.
Пример выражения:
[image: формула для примера]

сам сайт: http://ege.fipi.ru/os11/xmodules/qprint/index.php?theme_guid=2ef483029541e311b90c001fc68344c9&proj_guid=AC437B34557F88EA4115D2F374B0A07B

Comment: их рисует скрипт: ```<script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-1"><m:math><m:mstyle displaystyle="true"> <m:semantics> <m:mrow> <m:mfrac> <m:mrow> <m:msup> <m:mn>9</m:mn> <m:mrow> <m:mi>sin</m:mi><m:mn>2</m:mn><m:mi>x</m:mi> </m:mrow> </m:msup> <m:mo>−</m:mo><m:msup> <m:mn>3</m:mn> <m:mrow> <m:mn>2</m:mn><m:msqrt> <m:mn>2</m:mn> </m:msqrt> <m:mi>sin</m:mi><m:mi>x</m:mi> </m:mrow> </m:msup> </m:mrow> <m:mrow> <m:msqrt> <m:mrow> <m:mn>11</m:mn><m:mi>sin</m:mi><m:mi>x</m:mi> </m:mrow> </m:msqrt> </m:mrow> </m:mfrac> <m:mo>=</m:mo><m:mn>0</m:mn> </m:mrow>  </m:semantics> </m:mstyle></m:math>```

Comment: это я понимаю, но как мне получить выражение в нормальном виде?

Comment: что для вас "нормальный вид"? вы пишете "получить формулы и выражения в том виде в котором они должны быть на сайте фипи"... на сайте фипи они в виде скрипта

Comment: я их получаю вот так:  9  sin2x   − 3  2 2  sinx       11sinx     =0
а хотелось бы с дробной чертой и знаком корня

Comment: приведите в пример ожидаемый результат?

Comment: @Jack_oS, желательно как на скриншоте